# Term for the product of the coordinates of a position vector?

Tags: terminology, vectors

Suppose I have a position vector $v$ and I multiply its $x$-component by its $y$-component to get the product $p$.

Is there a single term to describe $p$?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: That isn't a well-defined operation on vectors (it's not invariant under change of coordinates).